# How to access a function from whiting another function in angularjs controller using 'this' keyword

Tags: function, angularjs, controller

I define a controller with its functions:

```
myApp.controller "SomeCtrl", ($scope) ->

 @go = (text) ->
   console.log(text)

 @go2 = () ->
   ??go('test')
```

'??' is what im struggling with.

If I assign these functions to $scope, then it's possible to just use $scope.go() .
How can I achive the same in this scenario ?

http://jsfiddle.net/K7aPq/10/

Comment: It's inside the same function, so have you tried to just call go('test') without a prefix?

Comment: yes Foo, I get 'ReferenceError: go is not defined'

Comment: It works for me using plain javascript. You should look at the source in the browser to see how your code gets compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it's not working for you. If I use plain Javascript, it works. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dafoo/K7aPq/2/

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    function foo1 (argument) {
      console.log('foo1');
      console.log(argument);
    };

    function foo2 () {
      console.log('foo2');
      foo1('test');
    };

    foo2();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Foo, but it's not working for me for some reason.  
I've added a fiddle to the original question

Comment: Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dafoo/K7aPq/16/  You missed a `this` in front of the call to `foo1('Superhero')`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs specifically in AngularJS, in controllers AND directives. Not sure why they chose to hijack `this`, when there are all kinds of dependency injection options... overkill.

Comment: Can you give more details, Nick?

Comment: @nbaleli Not really, but if you google "angular this keyword" you will see in the first and second page of results, various people mentioning the reuse of `this` in controller and directive scope, by the angular framework. Unfortunate but true. P.S. You could always just set a local variable to `$scope` so that you don't have to write out `$scope.whatever` every time. :/

Comment: @nbaleli My point was that to write correct code within the bounds of the framework, you shouldn't be using `this` in that way.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, I was testing the 'this' method because Ive seen some videos/tutorials using it. It's either use 'this' or '$scope' as you say, I find the 'this' syntax to be cleaner for me.

When you say I shouldn't be using 'this' in that way, what do you mean? use it inside functions that are assigned to the controller?